# File upload with Flask to S3 and local environment

Tags: flask, file-upload

I have an API built with Flask which needs to support file uploads. This is the flow I thought of:

1. User gets an upload URL `GET /upload-url` and Flask responds with `HTTP 201` and JSON `{'url': path-to-upload-url}`
2. User uploads the file directly to `url`

I would like this to work both interacting with Amazon S3 and my local environment when developing:

1. If local environment `url = /media/upload`, else `url = <S3 Signed URL generated with generate_presigned_url (boto3)`

How do I replicate the same behavior as S3 file upload when working locally? I need Flask to read the binary content of a PUT request in order to save the file to the local file system. I got the information on how to put files to S3 [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/). Specifically, I need the equivalent of `file = request.files.get('files[]')` which works for a mutipart form post. See Postman request:

[image]